# an irreducible polynomial over GF(2) is primitive over GF(2)

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

let $P \in  F_{2} [X]$ of degree $7$, how to prove this:

P is irreducible  $\Leftrightarrow$  P is primitive

i tried to use the **mersenne prime** !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  direction is  trivial.  Assume  P(x)  is a primitive. Then clearly  P(x) is irreducible over  Z_2 (Since  P(x) is the  minimal  monic  polynomial where  P(a) = 0  and    (a)   = GF^*(2^7).

Conversely, assume that  P(x) is irreducible.  Let a  be  a root of   P(x).  We know
Z_2(a)  is  ring-isomorphic to  Z_2[x]/(P(x)).  Thus  Z_2(a) = GF(2^7). 
Note that  GF*(2^7)  is a group under multiplication  and  |GF*(2^7)| =  127 = 2^7 - 1.  Note  that  127  is  a prime  number.  Hence  |a| =  2^7 - 1  = 127  (Note that  the order of each element  must  divide the order of the group by Lagrange).  Thus  a  is a primitive root  (other name  a is  (2^7 -1)-root of unity).   Let  m =  2^7-1. Since (a) = {1, a, a^2, ..., a^{m-1} },  P(x) is primitive.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Here is a MathJax tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Please consider editing your answer to make it more readable.

Comment: This answer is still readable (and correct, +1), but yeah, it is a good idea to learn a bit of TeX. You will be using it a lot later anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

A more general statement can be shown. All irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ in $GF(2)[x]$ are primitive if and only if $2^{n}-1$ is a (Mersenne) prime. Note that this means $n$ must also be a prime. It now suffices to compare the number of irreducible polynomials from Gauss formula $\frac{\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) 2^{\frac{n}{d}}}{n}$ and the number of primitive polynomials $\frac{\phi(2^n-1)}{n}$ where $\mu$ and $\phi$ are, respectively, the Moebius and Euler phi function. The numerator in the first formula is $2^n-2$ while in the second one it is $2^n-2$ if and only if $2^n-1$ is a prime.

Answer (score 0):

first a primitive polynomial is irreducible by definition.

For the other direction, if P is an irreducible polynomial of degree
$7$, it generates a field extension of $2^7 = 128$ elements over Z2.

The polynomial is primitive if the powers of one of its roots
generate the multiplicative group of the field. If the polynomial is
not primitive, the powers of its root only generate a proper
subgroup of that group.

However, the multiplicative subgroup of the fields consists of the
non-zero elements, which means that this group has order 127. As 127
is prime, the group does not contain any proper non-trivial
subgroup, by **Lagranges's theorem**.